# Removing code dynamically?

Tags: c++, dynamic

I'm in a for loop in C++ and i want an "if" clause inside of it to disappear in the next iteration (for the sake of performance) after it checks the value as true once. Is that possible in C++ or in any other language?

Comment: Well... Depending on your architecture and how much black magic you want to delve into, you could dynamically change the "if" command into either a `jump` or a `nop` instruction dynamically - self modifying code, but on any modern system, this won't fly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic to change to code dynamically. Executing an `if` clause in a loop is probably not super-expensive if the `if` condition is cheap to execute.

If the condition is expensive to evaluate, you may want to *protect* it with an extra boolean variable:

```
bool mustCheck = true;
size_t const n = ...; // number of iterations

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (mustCheck && theExpensiveCheck(...)) {
        mustCheck = false; // turn off the check now
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

If the goal is to execute the check on the first iteration only, you could test if the loop index is `0`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i == 0 && theExpensiveCheck(...)) {
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Another option that does not have an `if` inside the loop is to pull out the `if` completely, and execute it before the loop if the loop has at least one iteration:

```
size_t const n = ...; // number of iterations

if (n > 0) {
    // do check and execute loop body for first item
    if (theExpensiveCheck()) {
        ....
    }
}

// start regular loop, starting at index 1
for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    // execute loop body for other items
    ...
}
```

The modifications above add extra complexity (and thus potential bugs) to your code. I would recommend to not perform any of these modifications if it's unclear whether there actually is a perform problem with the loop or the `if` condition. Often enough, applying the above modifications will not result in substantial performance gains, but clearly it depends on the `if` condition.

Compilers nowadays also provide several powerful loop optimization techniques, so you should make sure you're compiling with all these optimizations turned on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in C++. Once it is compiled, that's it. But, you shouldn't worry about checking a value once. The performance impact is insignificant.

I suppose if the value check was pretty involved (ie more than simple checking if it is T or F), you could add some sort of flag to check first and then skip the rest of the check if it is true. This obviously requires its own check/assignment and is most likely not worth doing.